# GWT DialogBox : How can I do other actions during dialog was opened?

Tags: gwt

I would like to create GWT chat application. So I used [GWT DialogBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html) for chatting. For easy to chat , I don't want to see glass style of dialog. I setted `setGlassEnabled(false);` . Now I can't see glass but I got a problem. I can't select any text , can't click on any links or buttons of widgets these are not in dialog.

For instance, after I opened my chat dialog, I can't click on any of my header links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your dialog is not set to modal.

Comment: Thank you sir now I get with `super(false, false);` . I set modal to false.

Comment: Oh ! I can use `setModal(false)` method.